# Delete a published book using ITMS Transporter

Tags: command-line, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunes-sdk, itmstransporter

I have a program which properly published books to iBook Store using ITMS Transporter command line. 
Now i need a functionality which i can send a command which will un publish/delete by book from iBookStore as i migh

Comment: you shouldnt be asking code for what you have to achieve, but put in what you have tried for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (as of March 2015) it is not possible to delete/create new content (books/apps at least) with the command line tool/iTMS Transporter. You need to use iTunes Producer and/or iTunesconnect. iTMS Transporter only helps you to upload content, screenshots etc. or get the meta data of already created content.

There are some work arounds on the web for apps, maybe you should have a look over here: https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver Maybe you can integrate/use some of the tools.